# Resetting password redirection to myaccount doesn't work as expected

Tags: wso2-identity-server

When I create a User in my test application, an email is sent to the user to create a password in order to log in successfully to the application.
In this email, there is a link to set the password. After adding the new password and click the proceed button, we are redirected to the `/carbon` management page instead of `/myaccount` page.

By investigating more, I found out that if I try to access My Account Page passing a query param
`passwordReset=true` I get a `405 Method Not Allowed` error.

The version of wso2is is 5.11.0

What is the correct configuration so that after a user sets the password we could redirect him to log in directly to our test application or my account?

Comment: The explanation https://github.com/wso2/product-is/issues/12787

Answer (score 0):

You have to append the query parameter `callback` to define where you want to redirect after the reset. A sample reset password link

```
eg: https://{is-server}/accountrecoveryendpoint/confirmrecovery.do?confirmation=151cbca7-2961-45d7-a108-49f34ade6aea&userstoredomain=USER&username=sample&callback={test-application-url}&type=reset
```

Comment: I am landing at `https://{{domain}}/accountrecoveryendpoint/confirmrecovery.do?confirmation=20135e73-ee6c-4f0b-84db-49d7a15c8ff3&userstoredomain=PRIMARY&username={{username}}&tenantdomain={{tenant}}`
when I click the CREATE PASSWORD link on the Password change for New Account.
 Then a POST request to `/accountrecoveryendpoint/completepasswordreset.do` is made passing the form data having as callback `https://{{domain}}/myaccount`.
Finally, the GET request to `/myaccount&passwordReset=true` gives me a status code 405. So If I understand, this should have worked, but it doesn't